# I want to be able to show python script output in a terminal when using systemd on a raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Here is the current Unit definition:

```
[Unit] 
Description=Run control script for chicken coop door via python
After=multi-user.target 
Requires=network.target

[Service] 
Type=idle 
User=pi
ExecStart=/bin/python3.9/home/pi/Documents/Coop_Door_Final.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=60

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly show the output of a process controlled by systemd on a terminal (at least not with extra shenanigans), since `systemd` redirects regular stdout/stderr output to the journal.

However, you can set up `journalctl` to print out that output and follow along as more appears, and run that on your console.

```
journalctl -f -u yourunitname
```